# Userform button does react on user actions while runing the code

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I created a progress bar with a UserForm with a STOP button. This UserForm works well and executed while my scripts are running.

The issue is that I cannot move the userFom Window with the mouse or click on the STOP button when the macro is running.

I guess the CPU is used for executing the code and then the UserForm has "no time" to get user inputs/events.

How can I solve this issue ?

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: It's difficult to answer without any code to talk about, but in general, you'd want to add some `Sleep` statements combined with `DoEvents`, to tell your code to relinquish control rather than hogging all the CPU busy-waiting.

Comment: did you try opening the form as `vbModeless`? (it's not 100% clear to me your goal, btw)

Answer (score 3):

To tell Excel to leave the CPU-consuming code for a moment and handle events from the user you have to insert 
    DoEvents
in your code.
E.g. If you have a long for loop you can write `DoEvents` inside the for loop. So at every iteration Excel will handle user inputs.

We don't have a sample code from you, here it's mine.

```
Public Sub YourRoutine()
    Dim row_i As Long

    'CPU Time consuming loop
    For row_i = 1 To 9999999
        Cells(row_i,1).Value = "I'm row number" & vbCrLf & row_i & vbCrLf & "."
    Next i

End Sub
```

With the above code Excel will not answer to user inputs until the Sub ends.
Adding DoEvents as below code Excel will answer to user inputs every time row_i grows.

```
Public Sub YourRoutine()
    Dim row_i As Long

    'CPU Time consuming loop
    For row_i = 1 To 9999999
        Cells(row_i,1).Value = "I'm row number" & vbCrLf & row_i & vbCrLf & "."
        'Interrupt for events
        DoEvents
    Next i

End Sub
```

You may also want to do 10 steps and after those iterations listen for user inputs

```
Public Sub YourRoutine()
    Dim row_i As Long

    'CPU Time consuming loop
    For row_i = 1 To 9999999
        Cells(row_i,1).Value = "I'm row number" & vbCrLf & row_i & vbCrLf & "."
        'Interrupt for events every 10 iterations
        If row_i Mod 10 = 0 Then
            DoEvents
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

If you don't have a loop but a generic long code put `DoEvents` in every point you want Excel to listen to user events